# Sprite pointers in 6502 (Commodore 64)

Tags: assembly, 6502, commodore

So I'm trying to set my sprite pointers, but I can't seem to find out how to do it.

I know that if I want to set the pointer to be let's say **$2000** I should set the pointer (**$07F8**) to **#$80** since 40 * 80 = 2000. But what if I have my sprite binaries in the upper ram: **$C000**, I can't do that since that would be **#$300** and that's to big.

Comment: [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions) is the place for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VIC-II can address only 16KB of memory. This is probably because C-64 (VIC-40) first designed 16KB RAM in mind, later Jack Tramiel dictated that it will be 64K.

So the main memory divided into 4 banks:

```
0000-3FFF (0)
4000-7FFF (1)
8000-BFFF (2)
C000-FFFF (3)
```

So when you set VIC-II to 3rd bank (that is `C000-FFFF`) `$C000` becomes `0th` sprite.

Answer (score 2):

See the entries for 2040-2047 ($07f8-$07ff) and 53248 ($d000) in [Mapping the Commodore 64](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/9_Others/Compute/Compute%27s_Mapping_the_Commodore_64.pdf)

It is an invaluable resource for programming the C64.

As the other answer has stated, you need to control the graphics bank of the VIC-II chip.  The entry in Mapping the C64 for $DD00 explains it all:

> Bits 0 and 1 of CIA #2 Port A have an extremely important function. As
> mentioned in the section on the VIC-II chip (53248, $D000), the video
> chip can address only 16K of memory at a time, and all graphics data
> must be stored in that 16K block in order to be displayed. Within this
> area, sprite graphics data may be placed in any of 256 groups of 64
> bytes each. Character data can be stored in any of eight 2K blocks.
> Text screen memory may be in any of 16 IK areas, and bitmap screen
> memory may be in either of two 8K sections. When you turn the power
> on, the VIC-II uses the bottom 16K of memory for graphics.
> Unfortunately, this block of memory is also used extensively for other
> important purposes. Though some means of eliminating these conflicts
> are discussed above, in many situations you will want to change from
> the default 16K bank at the low end of memory. Bits 0 and 1 select the
> current 16K bank for video memory from the four possible choices using
> the following bit patterns: 00 (bit value of 0) Bank 3 (49152-65535,
> $C000-$FFFF) 01 (bit value of 1) Bank 2 (32768-49151, $8000-$BFFF) 10
> (bit value of 2) Bank 1 (16384-32767, $4000-$7FFF) 11 (bit value of 3)
> Bank 0 (0-16383, $0-$3FFF)